# What statistical method should I resort to to analyze the generational difference?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

So I would like to analyze the value attitude differences between two generations (Young people's generation and their parents' generation). I understand that normally independent t test or Anova can be used for this problem. The thing is, I PAIRED the children with their respective parent(so I collected data from 200 Child-parent pairs). Now, could someone please tell me what is the statistical method to analyze difference for this type of paired data?

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on the characteristics of the variables and on the exact research question(s) you want to study. I'll present 3 examples of application when both in the child and in their parents answered the same question:

- If you can assume the normality of the distribution of the variable at study (in principle a continuous variable), you can use the [paired t-Student's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Paired_samples) to compare the means of the groups.
- If normality is not assumed and the data is an interval scale (or at least ordinal), you can use the [Wilcoxon's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test) to compare the distributions using the mean ranks (you can compute the medians to get a feeling of the comparison).
- If you have a nominal variable, you can use [Cohen's k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) to study the agreement between answers.